# Getting xampp splash screen with .htaccess and codeigniter

Tags: .htaccess, codeigniter

I have the xampp installed on my local system. I am building a application with codeigniter and want to omit out the index.php in between.

here is my .htaccess file from here http://www.farinspace.com/codeigniter-htaccess-file/:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

### Canonicalize codeigniter URLs

# If your default controller is something other than
# "welcome" you should probably change this
#RewriteRule ^(welcome(/index)?|index(\.php)?)/?$ / [L,R=301]
#RewriteRule ^(.*)/index?$ $1 [L,R=301]

# Removes trailing slashes (prevents SEO duplicate content issues)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.+)/$ $1 [L,R=301]

# Enforce www
# If you have subdomains, you can add them to 
# the list using the "|" (OR) regex operator
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(www|subdomain) [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://localhost/masalewala/$1 [L,R=301]

# Enforce NO www
#RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.localhost/masalewala/$1 [L,R=301]

###

# Removes access to the system folder by users.
# Additionally this will allow you to create a System.php controller,
# previously this would not have been possible.
# 'system' can be replaced if you have renamed your system folder.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^system.*
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]

# Checks to see if the user is attempting to access a valid file,
# such as an image or css document, if this isn't true it sends the
# request to index.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

```
# Without mod_rewrite, route 404's to the front controller
ErrorDocument 404 /index.php
```

When accessing url: localhost/masalewala/anything, firefox give me the following:

"Firefox has detected that the server is redirecting the request for this address in a way that will never complete."

ANY CLUES?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not need all that in a .htaccess file. Try this, its what I use:

```
Options FollowSymLinks
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
</IfModule> 
<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
    ErrorDocument 404 /index.php
</IfModule>
```